# Google crawled page shows blank on screenshot tab

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, googlebot, google-crawlers, razzle

I have an page called https://www.bizibuz.com/ which made from React/Razzle with server side rendering.
From `View page source` or `URL inspection -> Live test -> HTML`, the html is returned correctly, but on the screenshot
it is always blank with a lot of js file couldn't be loaded.

I've tried [phantomjs](https://phantomjs.org/) which has a rumour that the fetch by google is using that to render page. However the page could be
rendered by that tool though.

Can anyone give any suggestion to how to make my page visible on google console screenshot? Or any idea about the root cause is appreciated too.
Thank you in advanced.